Solving a PDE for Temperature in a Cylinder with a Given Initial Condition
I am trying to solve the following partial differential equation that describes the temperature in a long cylinder:
$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = a^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}, \quad r > 0, t > 0$
subject to the initial and boundary conditions:

$ u(r, 0) = f(r), $
$ u(1, t) = 0, $
The temperature $ u(r, t) $ is bounded as $ r \to 0 $.

I am particularly interested in solving this PDE for the case where $ f(r) = 1 $. I am looking for an appropriate transformation to simplify and solve this equation, and I would like to write down the solution explicitly. Usually I would like to do this using Laplace transforming $u(r,t)$ to $\hat{U}(r,s)$. This obtains the following equation:
$r^2 \frac{\partial^2 U(r, s)}{\partial r^2}+r \frac{\partial U(r, s)}{\partial r}=a^2 r^2 s U(r, s)$
This is the Emden-Fowler equation. However, the difficult part here is that the solution of this equation does not really make sense since it will be:
$U(r)=c_1 J_0(i A r)+c_2 Y_0(-i A r), \quad A = a\sqrt{s}$
Where $J_0$ and $Y_0$ are respectively the Bessel functions of first and second kind. What did I do wrong or what can I do better?

This problem is perfect for separation of variables. Then you can get the solution as an infinite sum of Bessel functions.

Using Laplace transform with $U(r,s)=\mathcal{L}_t[u(r,t)](s)$
$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[a^2 \left(-\frac{\partial u(r,t)}{\partial t}\right)+\frac{\partial ^2u(r,t)}{\partial r^2}+\frac{\frac{\partial u(r,t)}{\partial r}}{r}\right](s)=-a^2 (s U(r,s)-u(r,0))+\frac{U^{(1,0)}(r,s)}{r}+U^{(2,0)}(r,s)=-a^2 (s U(r,s)-f(r))+\frac{U^{(1,0)}(r,s)}{r}+U^{(2,0)}(r,s)$$
With $f(r):=1$ we get the general solution of the ODE:
$$U(r,s)\to c_1 J_0\left(i a r \sqrt{s}\right)+c_2 Y_0\left(-i a r \sqrt{s}\right)+\frac{1}{s}$$
We are able to eliminate the integration constants with the constraints $U(\epsilon,s)=1, U(1,s)=0$:
$$\underset{\epsilon \to 0}{\text{lim}}(U(r,s))=\frac{1-\frac{J_0\left(i a r \sqrt{s}\right)}{J_0\left(i a \sqrt{s}\right)}}{s}$$
Now we have to apply inverse laplace transform:
$$u(r,t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}[\frac{1-\frac{J_0\left(i a r \sqrt{s}\right)}{J_0\left(i a \sqrt{s}\right)}}{s}](t)=2 \sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{J_0\left(r\cdot j_{0,k}\right)\cdot \exp \left(-\frac{t \left(j_{0,k}\right){}^2}{a^2}\right)}{j_{0,k}\cdot J_1\left(j_{0,k}\right)}$$
HINT: $j_{n,k}$ represents the $k^{th}$ zero of the Bessel function $J_n(x)$
Visualize solution with $a=2$:

The same result can be obtained by separation of variables $u(r,t)=R(r)\cdot T(t)$.
